# Java keeps giving me my coordinates multiplied by 93

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, grid-layout

When I set X and Y values for my array of `JButton`s, I get back the correct values only multiplied by 93. I can solve the problem by dividing the value by 93 but I would rather find out where the bug was in the first place.

I have two classes in the code, one for the actual program, and one for the button object along with the coordinates.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;
public class ConnectFour implements ActionListener
{
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     Button [][] buttons = new Button[6][7];
     public ConnectFour()
     {
         frame.setSize(700,600);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setTitle("Connect Four");
         for(int filler = 0; filler <= 5; filler++)
         {   
              for(int filler2 = 0; filler2 <= 6; filler2++) 
              {
                   buttons[filler][filler2] = new Button();
                   buttons[filler][filler2].setX(filler2);
                   buttons[filler][filler2].setY(filler);
                   //System.out.println(buttons[filler][filler2].getX());
                   //System.out.print(buttons[filler][filler2].getY());
                   frame.add(buttons[filler][filler2].button);
                   buttons[filler][filler2].button.addActionListener(this);
              }
         }
         frame.setVisible(true);
     }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
     {
         JButton pressedButton = (JButton)a.getSource();
         System.out.print(pressedButton.getY() / 93);
         System.out.print(pressedButton.getX() / 93);
     }
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          ConnectFour gameplay = new ConnectFour();
     }
}
```

Here's the `Button` class:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class Button
{
    JButton button;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    public Button()
    {
        button = new JButton();
    }
    public int getX() {return x;}
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public void setX(int xIndex) 
    {
        x = xIndex;
    }
    public void setY(int yIndex) 
    {
        y = yIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it comes down to the size of the buttons being 93 px..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing your two `Button` classes.

In this line, you're adding an actionListener to `Button.button`:

```
buttons[filler][filler2].button.addActionListener(this);
```

because `JButton` also has methods `getX` and `getY`, you can call them. When you do:

```
pressedButton.getX()
```

you're getting the `x` position of the `JButton`, not of your `Button`.

What I think would be the easiest way to solve this problem is making your button extend `JButton` and rename `x` and `y` to `row` and `column`, for instance:

```
public class Button extends JButton {
    private int row = 0;
    private int column = 0;

    public Button(int row, int column) {
        super();

        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;    
    }
    public int getRow() {return row;}
    public int getColumn() {return column;}
}
```

You can create you buttons as

```
for(int filler = 0; filler <= 5; filler++) {   
    for(int filler2 = 0; filler2 <= 6; filler2++) {
        buttons[filler][filler2] = new Button(filler2, filler);
        frame.add(buttons[filler][filler2]);
        buttons[filler][filler2].addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

And use them in the `ActionListener` as

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    Button pressedButton = (Button)a.getSource();
    System.out.print(pressedButton.getColumn());
    System.out.print(pressedButton.getRow());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure how to do it using your composition example, but this one works as you might want.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.*;

public class ConnectFour implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    CustomButton [][] buttons = new CustomButton[6][7];

    public ConnectFour()
    {
        frame.setSize(700,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Connect Four");
        for(int filler = 0; filler <= 5; filler++)
        {
            for(int filler2 = 0; filler2 <= 6; filler2++)
            {
                buttons[filler][filler2] = new CustomButton(filler,filler2);
                frame.add(buttons[filler][filler2]);
                buttons[filler][filler2].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
    {
        CustomButton pressedButton = (CustomButton)a.getSource();
        System.out.println(pressedButton.getRow() + "/" + pressedButton.getCol());
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ConnectFour gameplay = new ConnectFour();
    }
}

class CustomButton extends JButton
{
    private int row = 0;
    private int col = 0;

    public CustomButton(int row, int col)
    {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow() {return row;}
    public int getCol() {return col;}

    public void setRow(int row)
    {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public void setCol(int col)
    {
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 .....aaach half_sized without `get/putClientProperty`, reason from 2-3 insomnias weeks

Answer (score 0):

I think x and y are defined in the superclass, try changing the variable names to something else. e.g.

```
private int myX = 0;
private int myY = 0;
```

Comment: `Button` has no superclass, he uses composition rather than inheritance

Comment: oh yeah. Then getX on the JButton is nothing to do with the get and set in the custom Button class, and thus won't be the same value. You probably want a hashmap from JButton -> Button so you can use the source of the event to lookup the model object (Button)